# PHP preg_replace - replace all occurances

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, repeat

I currently have this chunk of PHP that replaces/removes certain HTML tag patterns:

```
$body = preg_replace('(<p><\/p>)', "", $body);
$body = preg_replace('(<div><br><\/div>)', "", $body);
$body = preg_replace('(<p><br><\/p>)', "", $body);
$body = preg_replace('(<p><ol>)', "<ol>", $body);
$body = preg_replace('(</ol></p>)', "</ol>", $body);
```

However, it's not removing **all** occurrences of the "tag patterns," only the first one.

I've seen some questions on SOF that pertain to this kind of issue, however, I haven't found one that has completely solved my problem.

Comment: You seem to be searching for literals. Why are you using `preg_` instead of `str_`?

Comment: Are you trying to strip out unnecessary tags? Like if your html code has: `<html>blabla<p></p> bleble</html>`

Answer (score 0):

To replace all occurences of the known string it would be wiser to use [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) as you know exactly what you want to replace.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason that `preg_replace` doesn't remove all occurrences since it makes by default a global search, and your patterns seem to be correct. Look at your string result a second time to ensure that the tags that aren't removed really match the pattern *(it isn't probably the case)*.

However, since you are replacing fixed substrings, you don't need to use a regex, a faster way is to use `strtr`:

```
$trans = array('<p></p>'         => '',
               '<div><br></div>' => '',
               '<p><ol>'         => '<ol>',
               '</ol></p>'       => '</ol>');

$body = strtr($body, $trans);
```

Using `preg_replace` will be necessary only if you want to deal with optional with optional blank characters. An other way, not always very handy but robust, is to use `DOMDocument`.